# Is there a way to delay when receiving a response from istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

I want to do a failure test of my application.
The main scenario is that my application calls a virtual external server and creates an error situation due to a delay in responding to the call.

I am using istio in k8s cluster.

I have looked into fault injection in istio, but that feature seems to cause a delay when my application is called.

What I want is when my application receives a specific API call from a client, it calls the API of a virtual external server and delays the response to the request in istio.

Is this possible in istio?
If possible, what should I do?

Best.

I registered an external server that does not belong to my mesh in serviceentry. I tried to control traffic coming from the domain used by the external server in istio, but of course it didn't work.